# Jquery Ajax's Alert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo, alert

I have multiple functions that has the same format of the following:

```
function xxx
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "orders.php",
        data: {"error":"0","type": "inform","result4": $orderid},
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {
        if (data.error != 0) {
            // An error occurred on server: do something 
        } else {
            Alert("Informed");
        }
    }
    });

    }
```

The other PHP file I call will return this:

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0, "result4"=>"Pass"));
```

1）How do I make it show the Alert, it doesn't want to run the alert.

2）How do I show a loading GIF loading on top of each of these as it is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `alert` not `Alert`

And you can use [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) as part of jquery to display the loading .gif

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#loading").show();
});
```

Where loading is the element with the `loading.gif`

Answer (score 0):

I think its typo **Alert**=>**alert**

Also function should have `()` in `function xxx`

Return after `encoding json` in `php`